# Cycles Subsurface shader: GPU compute and CPU compute give totally different results

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

Blender 2.67
Windows 7
Geforce gtx460

Head model with subsurface scattering and one texture
Cpu render - fine, but slow.
gpu render - face comes out black! (it was working at first it changed for some reason)

any suggestions? why should this happen.

Here is an image of the problem

[image: http://www.giantoakstudios.com/ShowBLack.jpg]

Comment: I don't think it's even rendering the SSS shader and is replacing it with the holdout shader (it will do that whenever the shader is either broken or not supported. BTW I got that reference :D)

Comment: Note that you can fake SSS on the gpu with the *Light path* node, see [this thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?280579-Absorption-Shader-including-SSS) on BlenderArtists

Comment: same problem in cycles with gts 240. what is SSS ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<s>The SSS shader has not been implemented for GPU rendering yet. It will always render black.</s>
**Update:** SSS now works on GPU, so they should look the same.

If you're looking for quick renders, SSS is not a good idea. If you can get away with a simple *Diffuse BSDF* shader with a bit of *Translucent BSDF*, that'd be great.

Comment: Thanks for the Advice Greg, In the end I used the SSS Shader and used CPU render, here is how it turned out http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?297366-General-Zod