# Images rendered on CPU and GPU are not the same

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Why is is my image different when rendered on CPU and GPU?

[image]

Comment: There should be no differerence (other than rendering time). What kind of GPU are you using?

Comment: Could you show your material setup? Currently (2.76) Subsurface Scattering Shader type works for GPU only with experimantal Feature set. Without, you won't see its contribution. Related: [Cycles Subsurface shader: GPU compute and CPU compute give totally different results](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/cycles-subsurface-shader-gpu-compute-and-cpu-compute-give-totally-different-res?rq=1)

Comment: My gpu is gt635m